# mvc3 remote validation progress bar on username

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use small progress bar infront of UserName on the cshtml page. How do I do that?
Is there a way?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
[Remote("IsUsernameAvalilable", "Validation")]
public string UserName { get; set; }

public JsonResult IsUsernameAvalilable(string userName)
{

    if (!_repository.UserExists(userName))
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return Json(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} is not available.", userName), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```